# How to "swipe right" between two people given information density?

Tags: design-patterns, mobile-application, choices

I'm not a UX designer, I'm a programmer. So please be patient with me :)

So we're working on a dating app that learns what features a user likes in other people. We're struggling with designing the 'preference learning' section, where users swipe on other users so our AI can learn who to recommend they message. The action space on this section is [select userA, select userB, neither].

At the moment, we have it setup like this, where users can swipe right to choose a person, select neither, or tap on the card to look at that person's profile:

[image]

We'd like to be able to directly include the person's "about me" and "about you" information on the cards because we suspect that this way will lead to decisions being based more on initial looks than personal qualities. However, this can be a lot of information, and simply overlaying it on a card like this would be too much.

Anyways, are there any previous designs doing something similar that we could base our design off of? Or are there any heuristics that would help us out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should determine the most important aspects of the profile and show that. Let's presume users looking for a date are more interested in looks, height and hobbies. You could then overlay that information over the image with an incentive to "read more" or "view complete profile".

It all turns down to what people really need and you need to find out by looking at studies or running them yourself.

Even if you would like for people to take decisions based on qualities you might find out that the majority of people base their decisions just on looks or the other way around. Find it out.